# when I add "<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />" to my web role definition, and attempt to deploy, it fails to start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure

When I add "" to my ServiceDefinition.csdef, it fails to start when publishing:

```
<WebRole name="xxx" vmsize="Small" enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
<Sites>...
```

Everything works with it gone.  Need to add it to specify machine key in Azure SDK 1.3, as described here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg494983.aspx

Anyone else run into this?

Would running under admin privileges cause other code to break?  When I RDP in, the error I find when I run on localhost is not related to this, but it's code that works when this runtime line is removed.

Answer (score 3):

> I just checked the [Service Definition Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557553.aspx) and the Runtime
>   element does not exist inside WebRole.

Actually it does.

```
 <WebRole name="<web-role-name>" vmsize="[ExtraSmall|Small|Medium|Large|ExtraLarge]" enableNativeCodeExecution="[true|false]">
   ...
   <Runtime executionContext="[limited|elevated]">
```

Answer (score -1):

I just checked the [Service Definition Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758711.aspx) and the Runtime element does not exist inside WebRole.

If you would like to have Full Trust, you should go to yor CloudService project properties and set it there. But i really don't know if you need that to specify the machine key.

Best regards